# Content Query Web Part modification issue

Tags: 2007, list, content-query-web-part

I am trying to display columns from 2 different lists in a site in CQWP. Most of the blogs and MSDN articles asks to modify the xslt file, ContentQueryMain.xsl and ItemStyle.xsl, for displaying additional columns. When I opened my site in SPD, I cannot find the Styles Library folder. Is there any specific settings? Also all the articles displays example to show additional column from single list. I have 2 lists with same columns, Title and Description (Multiline rich textbox) and I want to display basically Description in CQWP. Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ContentQueryMain.xsl` and `ItemStyle.xsl` are located in the Style Library in the RootSite of the sitecollection. Do not update the default styles defined is those files (others may depend on it). Rather add a new style to the file, or copy the files and update the references in the CQWP to the new XSL-files. To do this: export the webpart and update the corresponding properties: `HeaderXslLink`, `ItemXslLink` and `MainXslLink`.

In order to query multiple lists you must override the `<property name="ListsOverride" type="string" />` value in the webpart definition file. To do this, export the webpart. Open the file with your favorite xml/texteditor (notepad? visualstudio?). And update the property to: `<property name="ListsOverride" type="string"><![CDATA[<Lists><List ID="31A7C09D-52CC-4585-B998-A3F180A9BD07"/><List ID="7382D66D-2E4C-47CB-A95C-5EECD68F5E61"/></Lists> ]]></property>`. Use the ID's of the lists you want to query. When done import the webpart again. [(source)](http://www.glynblogs.com/2011/06/querying-specific-lists-with-the-content-query-web-part.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just one more query. Is it possible to display the top 1 item from each list rather than all list items?

Comment: Hmm, that depends on the data in your lists. And you probably have to write your own CAML-query (use the `QueryOverride` property).

Comment: I am still not able to display rich text content. I modified all settings. I can see my formatted text in textual format with some style sheets. Any help?

Comment: Rich Text is stored as HTML in the Database, use `<xsl:value-of select="somevalue" disable-output-escaping="yes" />` to display it. Otherwise all special char will be html-escaped (`& -> &amp;`)